# photologue django

Tags: django, photologue

I am trying to implement the photologue django photo gallery here:

http://skam.webfactional.com/blog/2007/08/08/django-based-photo-gallery-tutorial/

I dont understand this part:

You need to have the current user’s info outside requests, have a look at CookBookThreadlocalsAndUser  and add the middleware in your “MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES” settings.

Here the Link to CookBookThreadlocalsandUser:

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookThreadlocalsAndUser

What Middleware do I have to install?
What exactly is Threadlocals?
Is it possible to install this without fully understanding Threadlocals:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That blog entry is nearly three years old. Django has moved on considerably since then, and threadlocals - which was never anything more than a hack - is now officially warned against.

That's not the only thing that is out of date in that tutorial - all the references to admin are also now completely wrong.

However, that tutorial does not seem to have anything to do with photologue - it's a description of how to build your own custom gallery. Why don't you look at the [actual Photologue documentation](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) which appears to be very comprehensive?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have been to the official documentation. What I am looking for is an example code/project to understand the basics.